# HTML audio src changed with jQuery, but previous file is playing in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, audio, safari

I have a jQuery element, which on click, changes the src attribute of the  of an audio. I have printed the change in the HTML to the console, so I know the src is actually being changed. In Firefox (on OSX), this is fine: the src of the file changes and the audio that I hear also changes.

However, in Chrome and Safari (also on OSX), the src changes in the console as before, but the audio that plays is the previous file. Repeating the button click changes the src again, but Chrome and Safari will only ever play the first file.

Here is the initial HTML, which plays the word "slarg":

```
<audio id ="trget">
  <source id = "trget_wav" src = "slarg.wav" type = "audio/wav">
  <source id = "trget_mp3" src = "slarg.mp3" type = "audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Then, on a button click, this jQuery is executed:

```
$('#newWord').click(function() {
    var tar = $('#trget').html();
    console.log(tar);
    $("#trget_wav").attr("src",stim[2]).detach().appendTo("#trget");
    $("#trget_mp3").attr("src",stim[3]).detach().appendTo("#trget");
    var tar = $('#trget').html();
    console.log(tar);
});
```

Now, the html is changed to:

```
<audio id ="trget">
  <source id = "trget_wav" src = "blerg.wav" type = "audio/wav">
  <source id = "trget_mp3" src = "blerg.mp3" type = "audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

But in Safari and Chrome, it still plays the word "slarg", while in FF it will play the new word "blerg"...why? And more importantly, how do I get Safari and Chrome to do it right like FF?

Comment: Try changing the property instead of the attribute `$("#trget_wav").prop("src",stim[2])`

Comment: Unfortunately this just breaks it in Firefox too. The src attribute is effectively changing, but for some reason Safari/Chrome is not implementing the change of src file.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to call `stop()`, `load()`, and `play()` on the audio element to restart the audio etc.

```
$('#newWord').click(function () {
    var audio = $('#trget').get(0);

    audio.pause();

    $("#trget_wav").prop('src', stim[2]);
    $("#trget_mp3").prop('src', stim[3]);

    audio.load();
    audio.play();
});
```

Comment: This results in TypeErrors in all three browsers (and none of the code tied to newWord click executes).  The error in Safari and Chrome is: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'audio.stop()')" while in FF it's "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'stop'"

Comment: @Chrissy - Yeah, it should have been `pause()`.

Comment: Fantastic! Works now. I would upvote if I could. Also (maybe) worth noting that it works without the .play(), which I have tied to a separate click inside the html.